# Certain apps like supertux no loner exist after upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: software-center, games, 16.04

I attempted to find supertux in the dash but it seems to of disappeared. Also I couldn't find it in Ubuntu software when I tried to reinstall it. Actually, I can't any software except for software already installed on my system in the new software manger but I can in software center? Yet when I try to reinstall supertux in Ubuntu Software Center it says that "There isn’t a software package called “supertux-stable” in your current software sources." Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `supertux-stable` in 16.04. There's just `supertux`. From the [package index](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&keywords=supertux):

> #### Package supertux
>
> - xenial (games): Classic 2D jump 'n run sidescroller with Tux [**universe**]
>     `0.4.0-1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el s390x`